# F# - How to populate an System.Collections.Generic.List from array

Tags: f#

I have following code that populates a System.Collections.Generic.List I don't like it so I was wondering if there is a better way to do this.

```
let getDirectories = 
        Directory.GetDirectories(_baseFolder)
let languagesList = new System.Collections.Generic.List<string>()
Seq.cast getDirectories 
|> Seq.map(fun dir -> (new DirectoryInfo(dir)).Name) 
|> fun range -> languagesList.AddRange(range)
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
let list = new System.Collections.Generic.List<string>(arr)
```

`List<'T>` has a constructor that takes an `IEnumerable<'T>` so it happily takes any `seq<'T>` you pass to it.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to Mehrdad's answer

I find it helpful to define helper modules for many standard collections and .Net types to make them more F# friendly.  Here I would define the following

```
module BclListUtil =
  let ofArray (arr: 'T array) = new System.Collections.Generic.List<'T>(arr)
  let ofSeq (arr: 'T seq) = new System.Collections.Generic.List<'T>(arr)
```

Then you could change your original code to the following

```
let getDirectories = 
        Directory.GetDirectories(_baseFolder)
let languagesList = 
      getDirectiories
      |> Seq.map (fun dir -> (new DirectoryInfo(dir)).Name)
      |> BclListUtil.ofSeq
```

Comment: Note also that you can use the shorter (and potentially less ambiguous) type abbreviation `ResizeArray<_>` instead of `System.Collections.Generic.List<_>`.

Comment: @kvb, thanks, I didn't realize there was already a type alias present.

Answer (score 2):

The F# alias for `System.Collections.Generic.List<_>` is `ResizeArray<_>` as kvb noted. The [F# PowerPack](http://fsharppowerpack.codeplex.com/) includes a [ResizeArray module](http://fsharppowerpack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/42139#700896) for working with BCL Lists in an idiomatic F# fashion similar to the Seq and List modules.

However, for some strange reason this module seems to include `ofArray` and `ofList` and `toSeq` but not `ofSeq`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [ResizeArray](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/collections.resizearray%5B't%5D-type-abbreviation-%5Bfsharp%5D) that equals `System.Collections.Generic.List`

Example:

```
let languagesList = ResizeArray<string>()
languagesList.Add("1");
languagesList.Add("2");
```